# GWT - Issue with property change member variable being raised while loading the data first time

Tags: java, gwt, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, event-handling

I have a GWT application that loads a product when the page is loaded. I am using PropertyChangeEvent on the product object (and its sub-objects) to update the values of fields, whenever a change happens.

Of course, I do not want this PropertyChangeEvent to raise when the product is loaded for the first time. For this, I am setting the raisePropertyChange value to false, but it doesn't seem to work. Please find below the code base:

```
// Class ProductBaseImpl
public abstract class PropChangeImpl {

    // The raise property change event, should be turned off conditionally
    private boolean raisePropertyChangeEvent = true;

    protected boolean getRaisePropertyChangeEvent() {
        return this.raisePropertyChangeEvent;
    }

    protected void setRaisePropertyChangeEvent(final boolean value) {
        this.raisePropertyChangeEvent = value;
    }

    protected void raisePropertyChangeEvent(String fieldName, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        if (this.raisePropertyChangeEvent ) {
            // --> HERE IS THE PROBLEM <--
            // This IF loop must not be true when loading the product first time
            System.out.println("Property change event raised!");
            // the update operations go here
        } else {
            System.out.println("Property change event not raised!");
        }
    }
}

// Class ProductBaseImpl
public abstract class ProductBaseImpl extends PropChangeImpl {

    private static HandlerRegistration productChangeBeginRegistration;
    private static HandlerRegistration productChangeEndRegistration;

    protected E instance;

    protected ProductBaseImpl(final E instance) {
        this.instance = instance;

        // Stop updates when a new product loads
        if (ProductBaseImpl.productChangeBeginRegistration == null) {
            ProductBaseImpl.productChangeBeginRegistration = Core.getEventBus().addHandler(ProductChangeBeginEvent.TYPE, new  ProductChangeBeginEventEventHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onProductChangeBegin(final ProductChangeBeginEvent event) {
                    ProductBaseImpl.this.raisePropertyChangeEvent(false);
                }
            });
        }

        if (ProductBaseImpl.productChangeEndRegistration == null) {
            ProductBaseImpl.productChangeEndRegistration = Core.getEventBus().addHandler(ProductChangeEndEvent.TYPE, new ProductChangeEndEventtHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onProductChangeEnd(final ProductChangeEndEvent event) {
                    ProductBaseImpl.this.raisePropertyChangeEvent(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

// Class ProductSubObj1
public class ProductSubObj1 extends ProductBaseImpl {
    public ProductSubObj1 (final E instance) {
        super(instance);
        // some other operations
    }
}

// similar to above, I have classes ProductSubObj1, ProductSubObj2  ...


// Class ProductProvider, that fetches the product from service to UI
public class ProductProvider {

    // some properties and members

    public void fetchProduct(String productId) {

        // Let listeners know the product is about to change
        Core.getEventBus().fireEvent(new ProductChangeBeginEvent(productId));

        // Call the service to get the product in Json data

        // After processing the data to be available for the UI  (and scheduleDeferred)
        Core.getEventBus().fireEvent(new ProductChangeEndEvent(productId));
    }
}
```

As commented inline in the code, the control always goes within the

```
if (this.raiseDataChangeEvent)
```

block which I don't want to happen when the product is loaded for the first time.

Could you please advise what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do this:?

```
protected void raisePropertyChangeEvent(String fieldName, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        if (this.raisePropertyChangeEvent && oldValue != null /*Or whatever your default unloaded value is*/) {
            // --> HERE IS THE PROBLEM <--
            // This IF loop must not be true when loading the product first time
            System.out.println("Property change event raised!");
            // the update operations go here
        } else {
            System.out.println("Property change event not raised!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thats a good thought :) But I can't always go with null/default checks  as I've several sub-classes (sub-sub-classes) of ProductBaseImpl which has name/value pair being generated on the fly, and has too much of oldValue possibilities. I may run into maintenance complications :(

Comment: Well the best plan b I can think of is to register the event on the product object until after it's initial load.

Comment: Could you please advise what is wrong with the above code? I was thinking that the ProductBaseImpl.this.raisePropertyChangeEvent(false); in ProductBaseImpl class should make the property change event set to false until the ProductChangeEndEvent is fired.